# Run TomoChain node get error "etherbase must be explicitly specified"

Tags: blockchain, tomochain

We sending this command

```
tomo --rpc --port 30304 --rpcport 8547 --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcaddr "127.0.0.1" --rpcapi admin,db,eth,debug,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3
```

Load all like ethereum and then:
Fatal: Can't verify masternode permission: etherbase must be explicitly specified

Answer (score 2):

You will have to create a tomo account, what its telling you now is that no account is available for it to start mining, try :

```html
tomo account new
```